# How to not align << operators in C++ VSCode Mac using clang format

Tags: c++, visual-studio-code

It has been very annoying experience when vscode auto formats my code in unexpected ways. Ine such way is the following

```
std::cout << "Absolute" << "\n\n\n";
```

WhenI try to format the above code, (as part of another bigger piece of code, I get

```
std::cout << "Absolute"
          << "\n\n\n";
```

Is there a way to prevent this behavior?

my settings.json file if anyone is curious

```
{
    "C_Cpp.updateChannel": "Insiders",
    "update.mode": "manual",
    "cmake.configureOnOpen": true,
    "editor.minimap.enabled": false,
    "[cpp]": {
        "editor.defaultFormatter": "ms-vscode.cpptools"
    },
    "workbench.iconTheme": "vs-seti",
    "files.exclude": {
        "bin/": true,
        "data/": true,
        "obj/": true
    }
    
}
```

Comment: no, you'll need to turn off formatting for those lines. But why don't just use `std::cout << "Absolute\n\n\n";`

Comment: @phuclv this is just an example. I isometries select the whole file and then try to auto format and lot of << get aligned when I do not want them to.